# Swift: how to convert Optional("Optional(str)") to Int

Tags: swift, casting, option-type

In my Swift class I have the following:

```
var detailItem: Task?
var cellData:[String:String] = [:]

/* prepareForSegue not called before */
if (detailItem == nil) {
        self.cellData = ["id":"", "titolo":"", "oggetto":"", "check_mail":"", "progetto_nome":"", "assegnato_a":"", "richiesto_da":"", "priorita":"", "termine_consegna":"", "stato":"Aperto"]
    }

/* prepare for segue has been called */
else {
        self.cellData["id"] = String(stringInterpolationSegment: self.detailItem!.id)
        self.cellData["titolo"] = self.detailItem!.titolo
        self.cellData["oggetto"] = self.detailItem!.oggetto

        if (self.detailItem!.check_mail) {
            self.cellData["check_mail"] = "true"
        }
        else {
            self.cellData["check_mail"] = "false"
        }

        self.cellData["progetto_nome"] = self.detailItem!.progetto_nome
        self.cellData["assegnato_a"] = self.detailItem!.assegnato_a
        self.cellData["richiesto_da"] = self.detailItem!.richiesto_da
        self.cellData["priorita"] = self.detailItem!.priorita

        self.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        self.cellData["termine_consegna"] = self.dateFormatter.stringFromDate(self.detailItem!.termine_consegna)

        self.cellData["stato"] = self.detailItem!.stato

        var editButton:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Modifica", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "switchMode:")
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButton
    }
```

where some properties of the Task class are optionals (like the id) and so they may be nil.
When I need to perform a task update operation I need to retrieve the data from cellData, create a task object and use it to update the database which requires an id. So this is what I do:

```
var taskToUpdate = Task(id: self.cellData["id"]!.toInt(),
                        ...)
```

The problem is that id is always set to nil. I have tried:

```
println(self.cellData["id"]!.toInt())
```

and what I get is this:

```
Optional("Optional(102)").
```

Which is the correct way to cast that into Int?

Comment: `toInt()` itself returns an optional so you have to force unwrap in the end.

Comment: @Sulthan: I have tried with self.cellData["id"]!.toInt()! but I get "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value", though println(self.cellData["id"]!) shows Optional(54)...I don't understand, really :(

Answer (score 1):

The function `toInt()` returns always an optional because there are only a few cases where strings can be converted to integers. If you can ensure that the value is never nil, unwrap it

```
println(self.cellData["id"]!.toInt()!)
```

otherwise use optional bindings

```
If let idInt = self.cellData["id"]!.toInt() { println(idInt) }
```

Comment: I had tried what you've written, and what I get it nil...in both instructions. Maybe it's stringInterpolationSegment that makes things go wrong. Task class has other properties which are Int? but only with the id XCode wants me to put stringInterpolationSegment...

Comment: Actually, you should probably use `Int(....)` instead of `toInt()`. The best solution that will resolve all problems is using a custom struct/class instead of a dictionary. You won't have to access properties by name and you won't have optionals.

Comment: I have tried with self.cellData["id"]!.toInt()! but I get "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value", though println(self.cellData["id"]!) shows Optional(54)...I don't understand, really :(

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems there:

1. `.toInt()` returns an optional.
2. The `id` in `self.detailItem!.id` is probably an optional, too.

The result is that an optional `id` with value `102` is converted to `"Optional(102)"` and not `"102"` as you would expect.

I would advise you a simple solution - don't use dictionaries to hold your data, use objects where properties have the correct types. Don't go around converting your numbers to strings and back. Otherwise you will have to put force unwraps everywhere, e.g.:

```
String(stringInterpolationSegment: self.detailItem!.id!)
```

Comment: Yes, id in self.detailItem!.id is an optional too because a new created task has not an id (which will be given by the DB) and so is nil, while an already existing task to me modified has an id...that's why I had though to declare id as Int?....do you know how I can solve my problem? maybe declaring id as a simple Int?

Comment: @LoryLory There are many solutions. You could use `0` as a default ID. Or just check that `id` is not `nil`. The problem is not that `id` is `nil`. The problem is that you are converting it to string and back to integer incorrectly and unnecessarily.

Comment: Consider to redesign the model for example to use a non-optional `id` and assign 0 as "empty" id.

Comment: @Sulthan: I didn't think that way was incorrect...according to you which would?